# php simplexml grouping objects

Tags: php, xml, group-by, simplexml

Before I start I would like to say I am a noob at reading XML into PHP but I have so far managed to load XML and display the data onto a PHP page.
My next test is to group items.

Here is an XML snippet:

```
    <MailboxDatabases>
      <MailboxDatabase>
        <DatabaseName>DB01</DatabaseName>
        <Status>Healthy</Status>
        <MailboxServer>MB08</MailboxServer>
        <ActiveDatabaseCopy>mb07</ActiveDatabaseCopy>
        <ActivationSuspended>False</ActivationSuspended>
        <SinglePageRestore>0</SinglePageRestore>
        <ContentIndexState>Healthy</ContentIndexState>
        <Active>false</Active>
      </MailboxDatabase>
      <MailboxDatabase>
        <DatabaseName>DB01</DatabaseName>
        <Status>Healthy</Status>
        <MailboxServer>MB07</MailboxServer>
        <ActiveDatabaseCopy>mb07</ActiveDatabaseCopy>
        <ActivationSuspended>False</ActivationSuspended>
        <SinglePageRestore>0</SinglePageRestore>
        <ContentIndexState>Healthy</ContentIndexState>
        <Active>true</Active>
      </MailboxDatabase>
    <MailboxDatabases>
      <MailboxDatabase>
        <DatabaseName>DB02</DatabaseName>
        <Status>Healthy</Status>
        <MailboxServer>MB08</MailboxServer>
        <ActiveDatabaseCopy>mb07</ActiveDatabaseCopy>
        <ActivationSuspended>False</ActivationSuspended>
        <SinglePageRestore>0</SinglePageRestore>
        <ContentIndexState>Healthy</ContentIndexState>
        <Active>true</Active>
      </MailboxDatabase>
      <MailboxDatabase>
        <DatabaseName>DB02</DatabaseName>
        <Status>Healthy</Status>
        <MailboxServer>MB07</MailboxServer>
        <ActiveDatabaseCopy>mb07</ActiveDatabaseCopy>
        <ActivationSuspended>False</ActivationSuspended>
        <SinglePageRestore>0</SinglePageRestore>
        <ContentIndexState>Healthy</ContentIndexState>
        <Active>false</Active>
      </MailboxDatabase>
    </MailboxDatabases>
```

As you can see, "DatabaseName" is the same in two items but "Active" is different.
What I want to do is display the above xml in php like

DB01 - MB08 - false | DB01 - MB07 - true

DB02 - MB08 - true | DB01 - MB07 - false

using the following elements
(database) - (Mailboxserver) - (active) | ...

Please could someone give me a hand and also please try to explain the code.

Comment: your xml is invalid, probably you forgot to delete that `<MailboxDatabases>` on line 22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Overall strategy:**

1. create a list of unique groups, that is `<DatabaseName>`
2. select all `<MailboxDatabase>` that belong to a group and echo their `<MailboxServer>` and `<Active>`
3. proceed to the next group and go to step 2 until you iterated over all groups.

It's time to learn about selecting certain nodes from an XML, and this is best done with `xpath`. In short, `xpath` is for XML what SQL is for databases.

Let's say you have a `SimpleXML` object ready:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
```

**create a list of unique groups**

Get all `<DatabaseName>` in an array:

```
$groups = $xml->xpath("/MailboxDatabases/MailboxDatabase/DatabaseName");
```

`$groups` contains an array of `SimpleXML` elements now, so let's do some array-magic to transform those into strings:

```
$groups = array_map("strval", $groups);
```

Result (`var_dump`):

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "DB01"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "DB01"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "DB02"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "DB02"
}
```

Some more array-magic: make it a unique list by flipping keys and values, keys must be unique, so duplicates are killed. then flip again:

```
$groups = array_flip(array_flip($groups));
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(4) "DB01"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "DB02"
}
```

This is it. Write it as one line:

```
$groups = array_flip(array_flip(array_map("strval", $xml->xpath("//MailboxDatabase/DatabaseName"));
```

BTW: `//` at the beginning of that `xpath` statement is a wildcard

**select nodes group-wise**

Again `xpath`, this time with a condition to select only those `<MailboxDatabase>` that share the same `<DatabaseName>`. Note the condition in `[]`:

```
$elements = $xml->xpath("/MailboxDatabases/MailboxDatabase[DatabaseName = '$group']");
```

Now iterating over `$groups`:

```
foreach ($groups as $group) {

    echo "group $group:" . PHP_EOL;
    $elements = $xml->xpath("//MailboxDatabase[DatabaseName = '$group']");

    foreach ($elements as $e)
        echo "  " . $e->MailboxServer . ": " . $e->Active . PHP_EOL;

    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Result:

```
group DB01:
  MB08: false
  MB07: true

group DB02:
  MB08: true
  MB07: false
```

see it working: https://eval.in/321935

Comment: thank you for your help, I am a little tired at the moment to take in your explanation so will go through it tomorrow. Again, thank you very much